# pagination labels show with hover

Tags: pagination, hover, label

I've got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
      $.scrollIt();
    }); 

      $("a").hover(function(){
        $(".label").show();
        },function(){
        $(".label").hide();
      });
});
```

The problem is this: I have a list with multiple a's. When I hover anyone of them now, all objects with the class '.label' will show. But I just want the one that belongs to the 'a' i'm hovering over to show up.

Anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
  var element = $(this);
  $(element).next(".label").show();
  //or just: $(this).next(".label").show();
  },function(){
  $(".label").hide();
});
```

instead of:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(".label").show();
    },function(){
    $(".label").hide();
  });
```